# Adding birthdays and anniversary to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I know how to add a yearly event but is there an option to add birthdays and/or anniversaries to Google Calendar?

I am not talking of the "Birthday calendar" but manually adding a birthday event to my existing calendar.

I can't seem to find any such option.

Comment: I wrote myself [a simple web app](http://birthdayfeed.subtlecoolness.com/) that takes a spreadsheet of birthdays and produces an .ics url that I can subscribe to in Google Calendar. I get events with names such as "Lauren Ipsum turns 26" on the appropriate days.

Comment: Google Calendar doesn't distinguish event types (e.g. note, anniversary, or birthday).

Answer (score 5):

It is unclear what special feature you want a yearly event does not provide. My suggestion is to create a new calendar, label it something like "Anniversaries", then start recording yearly events.

On the other hand, birthdays are supposed to be recorded to Google Contacts. However, all birthdays show up in Birthdays Calendar and I'm not aware of an easy way to hide certain people or circles from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a yearly event and label it "Person ABC's birthday"?

If you are having problems with recurring events, then you can address that by changing the duration from "never ends" to a finite number of years.

Comment: as mentioned i already know it but can i set the event type

Comment: My apologies, I am not aware of any classification by event type. All I do is choose event color to distinguish between events (within one calendar).

Comment: Google Calendar doesn't have a concept of "event type".

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

- You can create a contact for yourself in Google Contact
- Set yourself-contact as Your Info in Google Contact App Or
  use set yourself-contact as me with Google Assistant
- Congrats, Google Calendar detect all birthdays and
  anniversaries